# Inverting a linear transformation from $L^2$ to $R^N$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f(t) \in L^2$ and $\{\alpha_i(t)\}$ be a set of $N$ linearly independent functions in $L^2$. Let the $i$th entry of $b \in R^N$ equal $\int f(t) \alpha_i(t)dt$.

Is there a general method for solving for $f(t)$ given $b$? I realize that the solution is in general not unique, but I was wondering if there was a general way to find any such solutions (perhaps the minimum norm solution?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of the $\alpha_i$. Let be $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^N$ the new subspace basis. Write the coefficients $c_i = \int f\beta_i$ depending on the $b_i = \int f\alpha_i$. The sum $\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\beta_i$ will be a solution of your problem.

Comment: If we make the new subspace basis orthonormal, would this also be the minimum norm solution? It would seem so, since an orthonormal expansion preserves the norm and all the "unnecessary" components to fill the rest of $L^2$ are effectively set to zero.

Comment: @Probably, right.